Problem in computing a sum.

For a multi-index $\alpha = \left (\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_n \right )$ we write $\left \lvert \alpha \right \rvert = \alpha_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n$ and $\alpha! = \alpha_1! \cdots \alpha_n!.$ For $z = (z_1, \cdots, z_n) \in \mathbb C^n$ and multi-index $\alpha = \left (\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_n \right )$ let $z^{\alpha} = z_1^{\alpha_1} \cdots z_n^{\alpha_n}.$ Define $e_{\alpha} : \mathbb D \longrightarrow \mathbb C$ by $$e_{\alpha} (z) = \left (\frac {\Gamma \left ( \left \lvert \alpha \right \rvert + n + \gamma + 1 \right )} {\Gamma \left (n + \gamma + 1 \right ) 
\alpha!} \right )^{\frac {1} {2}} z^{\alpha},$$
where $\gamma > - 1.$ Then find $\sum\limits_{\alpha} e_{\alpha} (z) \overline {e_{\alpha} (w)},$ where the sum is taken over all the multi-indices $\alpha = \left (\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_n \right ).$


This sum is actually the expression of the Bergman reproducing kernel of a certain weighted Bergman space. In the paper Compact Toeplitz Operators on Bergman Spaces by K.Stroethoff this sum is claimed to be $\frac {1} {\left (1 - \left \langle z, w \right \rangle \right )^{n + \gamma + 1}}.$

Could anyone shed some light on this fact as to how the sum is of the desired form? Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks for your time.

If you look at how the binomial theorem works for $(1-x)^{-s}$ you should be able to extend to a multinomial case which handles your series.

@LeeFisher$:$ Could you please explain in detail? I don't see how the coefficients are obtained in terms of Gamma function.

Try it with $\gamma\geq 0$ and an integer. You can replace the Gamma functions with factorials and write the coefficients explicitly as multinomial coefficients.
